# back commandbutton in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, navigation, back-button

how would one implement a back-button as a commandbutton that works universally? with back button i don't mean the browser-button, but rather a button that sits somewhere on the page. it is not always possible to use the Post-redirect-get pattern.

its quite impractial to pass around the information on every single where the button should point to.

is there maybe a reserved keyword for a navigation rule that points to the last navigation rule applied?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use a `h:commandLink` with attribute `onclick="history.go(-1)"` in this case. It works universally.

Comment: Was hoping this would help me out, but doesn't appear to work with h:commandButton.  :-(

Comment: Do you really need to use a jsf tag for this? If not, try with <input type="button" onclick="history.go(-1)" />. It will work.

Comment: It seems to refresh the current page, which is no longer being displayed, so any ManagedProperties will get null pointer exceptions. Any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: I used `onclick="history.go(-1);return false;"` to prevent submission of the original page.

Comment: i have the same problem "null pointer exceptions" when i go back in the history :/ i am pass params to my bean. :/ onclick="history.go(-1);return false;" works to return, but, when i do clic on other button, the jsf have this error : Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null

Comment: i resolve my problem, using h:button in the root page, so, when i do 'onclick="history.go(-1);return false;"' we don't have problem on "null pointer exceptions", sorry if i write with bad ortography, but i'm spanish speaker, my english is bad :D

Answer (score 3):

My first idea :

on every

```
<h:commandLink .....>
```

and etc; store the navigation string in a bean, or even a stack, and then the back button can retrieve it and just return that as per faces-config.xml

Second idea.

But on reflection you should override or use a filter to intercept the navigation commands and push them onto a stack.  Then the back button can just pop the navigation off and away you go.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="window.history.back();"/>
```

That instruction do the same as `onclick="history.go(-1)"` which alexmeia has said.

Comment: Bad way of using a commandButton. Either use a `p:button` or add 'type="button" to it. See the PrimeFaces documentation for this!

Answer (score 1):

I would store the navigation string in a stack datatype and you use the stack.peek() to show which is the site behind you, and when its clicked you fire an action event that triggers the stack.pop()

Answer (score -1):

I have used the "previous" button in my tab view and the navigation is working smoothly by just using

```
 <p:commandButton value="Previous" id="PreviousOffer" onclick="window.history.go(-1);return false;"/>
```

P.S.- When I did not use `return false;` and I clicked on the previous button, it stays on the current page only. However, after adding `return false` it started working.

Comment: better to add a `type="button"` to it as well, then the return false is not needed