# JSF Back Button

Tags: jsf, navigation, back-button

How do I make a link which navigates the user back one page (i.e. same as clicking browser back)?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649834/back-commandbutton-in-jsf

Answer (score 6):

To the point: just remember the request URL or the JSF viewId of the previous page so that you can use it in the href or value of the output/commandlink. There are several ways to achieve it, depending on how you're actually navigating through the pages and how "jsfish" you want to achieve it. You could pass it as a request parameter by `f:param` in `h:outputLink`, or you could set it as a bean property by `f:setPropertyActionListener` in `h:commandLink`, or you could create a `PhaseListener` which remembers the `viewId` and make use of navigation cases, or you could grab the -[much less reliable](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+history.go+problem)- JavaScript `history.go()` function.

Comment: I'm missing something here.  Trying to implement the history.go() method of going back (because I have to go back to non-JSF pages too), but the javascript doesn't run.  immediate=true and onclick of history.go(-1).  The onclick javascript never gets called, the page refreshes instead.

Comment: @Brian: Press `Ask Question` button if you stucks. Post an SSCCE if you can.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.  Needed to set "type=button" as well...

Comment: BalusC: do you think you can elaborate the use of `PhaseListener`? Maybe add a bit more code into it?