# How to get back to same JSF page on Pressing of some button from another JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, navigation

I have two JSF pages,suppose A and B.From these two pages A and B I can navigate to page C.Now there is a button(OK button) in page C,clicking on which it should navigate back to either A or B depending upon from where(either A or B),page C was called.Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [back commandbutton in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649834/back-commandbutton-in-jsf)

Answer (score 6):

### Solution that utilizes view parameter

The idea is that you can pass the current view id as a get parameter of the next (target) page. From the target page you will be able to use it to navigate back.

Basic example:

Views A & B:

```
<h:body>
    Hello from page A (B)
    <h:link value="Go to page C via link" outcome="target">
        <f:param name="backurl" value="#{view.viewId}"/>
    </h:link>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Go to page C via command button" action="#{baseBean.doAction}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

View C:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="backurl" value="#{backBean.backurl}"/>
</f:metadata>
<h:body>
    Hello from page C
    <h:link value="Go back via link" outcome="#{backBean.backurl}">
    </h:link>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Go to page C via command button" action="#{backBean.back}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Bean of pages A / B:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BaseBean {

    public String doAction() {
        String url = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId();
        return "/target?faces-redirect=true&backurl=" + url;
    }

}
```

Bean of page C:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BackBean {

    private String backurl;

    public String back() {
        return backurl + "?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String getBackurl() {
        return backurl;
    }

    public void setBackurl(String backurl) {
        this.backurl = backurl;
    }

}
```

The last point to mention is that view id may *differ* from URL in a web browser.

### Enhancement to the solution when only `<h:link>` is used

Taking into consideration the rightful comment by BalusC and his previous answer on the question [Cancel button doesn't work in case of validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148566/cancel-button-doesnt-work-in-case-of-validation-error/13149506#13149506), in case you don't need to employ `<h:commandButton>` in the target page, thus do not need to do any business job when going back to the previous page, you can essentially leave the job to `<h:link>`. In this scenario the backing bean (of the target view) is not needed at all and the structure of the target view can be minimized to:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="backurl"/>
</f:metadata>
<h:body>
    Hello from page C
    <h:link value="Go back" outcome="#{backurl}" rendered="#{not empty backurl}"/>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Note that in case of `<h:link>` in C the whole bean is unnecessary. Just get rid of `value` attribute of `<f:viewParam>` and use `outcome="#{backurl}"`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148566/cancel-button-doesnt-work-in-case-of-validation-error/13149506#13149506

Comment: @BalusC Of course, but in that case we'll have to remove the value binding of `<f:viewParam>`, otherwise it will be empty. Ah, edits, edits :)

Comment: Uhm, did I tell otherwise?

Comment: @BalusC By the way, can you check out [what's wrong with my solution with internalization problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15121121/1820286), because I can't get it fully working?

Comment: what mean `rendered="#{not empty backurl}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a property `comesFrom` in your Beanclass. This property you can give the name of your page where you're coming from when navigating to page `C` (`A` if it's page A, `B` if it's page B).
On click on your OK button in your page `C` you can check your property `comesFrom` and navigate back to the value of the property.